# EF Core 2.1 foreign key with different datatype

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have thes model classes:

```
public partial class InventoryCustomer : EntityBase, ICrudEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? SlsalesLevelTypeId { get; set; }
    public long? SalesLevelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual GroupOfCustomer GroupOfCustomer { get; set; }
}

public partial class Customer : EntityBase, IPkEntity<long>
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InventoryCustomer> InventoryCustomer { get; set; }
}

public partial class GroupOfCustomer : EntityBase, ICrudEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InventoryCustomer> InventoryCustomer { get; set; }
}
```

Property Id must remain an `int` at `GroupsOfCustomer` and `long` at `Customer`.

Depends of SlsalesLevelTypeId, SalesLevelId at InventoryCustomer references either on Customer or GroupOfCustomer.

Map class look like this:

```
 public class InventoryCustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<InventoryCustomer>
 {
     public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<InventoryCustomer> builder)
   {
    builder.ToTable("InventoryCustomers");

    builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

    builder.Property(e => e.SalesLevelId).HasColumnName("SalesLevelID");

    builder.HasOne(d => d.Customer)
        .WithMany(p => p.InventoryCustomer)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.SalesLevelId)
        .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.Id);

    builder.HasOne(d => d.GroupOfCustomer)
          .WithMany(p => p.InventoryCustomer)
          .HasForeignKey(d => d.SalesLevelId)
          .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.Id);
    }
}
```

But when I run code, I get an error:

[image]

Comment: Outside of EF - let me tell you that having this is something you WILL pay a significant price for. I had that multiple times in my career and even if you get it working, the price may be a SIGNIFICANT CPU usage because you CAN NOT compare those two values without casting. We talk of moving from a barely working CPU to a 100% maxed out queries getting slow CPU. Granted, though, this is brutally worse when you use character based PK's.

Comment: You cannot point a foreign key to multiple table. A foreign key is dedicated for one table at the same time.